# How to access data from Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in python which looks like:

Edit: Sorry, the data looks like follows:

```
1. [array([[[23,  2]]]), array([[[21,  2]],

               [[21,  3]],

               [[21,  4]],

               [[22,  4]],

               [[23,  4]],

               [[22,  4]],

               [[21,  3]]])]
2. [array([[[28, 26]],

       [[28, 27]],

       [[28, 28]],

       [[28, 29]],

       [[28, 30]],

       [[29, 30]],

       [[30, 30]],

       [[31, 30]],

       [[31, 29]],

       [[31, 28]],

       [[31, 27]],

       [[30, 26]],

       [[29, 26]]])]
    And after using print array_name[0] it looks like this:
        1. [[[23  2]]]
        2. [[[28 26]]

         [[28 27]]

         [[28 28]]

         [[28 29]]

         [[28 30]]

         [[29 30]]

         [[30 30]]

         [[31 30]]

         [[31 29]]

         [[31 28]]

         [[31 27]]

         [[30 26]]

         [[29 26]]]
```

Now I would like to read only the first part, i.e. [23 2] and [28 26]. How do it do that?

The list is divided into multiple arrays.

Comment: use print array_name[0] give its index to print the required data.

Comment: Yes, I tried that way, but it prints the whole [[[X X]] [[X X]]] present in the array

Comment: That is not valid python code. Please print and copy your array here so we can see what it actually looks like!

Comment: I have updated the question, kind help me.

Comment: How did u got array in python

Comment: I have tried using for loop:
for i in array_name[0]:
    print i[0]
    break
It does my job, but is there any other valid method?

Comment: There is no such array type in Python. May this rather be a question on numpy's array indexing/slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy
l1 = [numpy.array([[[23, 2]]]), numpy.array([[[21, 2]], [[21, 3]], [[21, 4]], [[22, 4]], [[23, 4]],
     [[22, 4]], [[21, 3]]])]

l2 = [numpy.array([[[28, 26]], [[28, 27]],[[28, 28]], [[28, 29]], [[28, 30]], [[29, 30]], [[30, 30]], [[31, 30]],
     [[31, 29]], [[31, 28]],[[31, 27]], [[30, 26]],[[29, 26]]])]

print l1[0]     # -> [[[23  2]]]
print l2[0][0]  # -> [[28 26]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed using the other [0].

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help. Best regards, zinjaai